# Two Postfix and one dovecot

Tags: postfix, smtp, dovecot

I need to setup 2 (physical) Postfix server and on one I want to install dovecot.

Both Postfix will have same MX priority. I would prefer to have the dovecot Mailstorage folder on a NFS share. Both postfix are responsible for same 2 domains.

What's the best way to get all incoming Mails Postfix on Server B to dovecot which stay on Server A? 
Or should I setup that both Postfix store Mail in the same NFS share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using LMTP to deliver mail from both Postfix instances to Dovecot. This also eliminates the need for NFS and is simpler to setup.

See [here](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixDovecotLMTP) for details.

Comment: Ok this would work for the Postfix on same server as Dovecot but what's with the other Server? I can not use a socket as there is no dovecot.

Comment: Nenad, see my answer for clarification on the role of the MTAs in this.

Comment: LMTP works over inet sockets too, not just UNIX ones. Just setup an IP listener in dovecot and point postfix to it. The configuration is the same.

Comment: @Luca Corti Do you know how it can be pointed to a IP Listener, In the manual they only show local solutions like:  argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver

Comment: Deliver is Dovecot `LDA`, which is an alternative delivery method to LMTP which works only locally. The link I gave you explains the LMTP setup and details the configuration using a unix socket as an example.  The configuration for an IP socket is the same, you just need to specify an `inet_listener` instead of a `unix_listener` in Dovecot and in postfix specify the transport accordingly. See the documentation for all the details.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving aside the details of LTMP, about which I know little, Luca's answer seems sound.  You have a Mail Transport Agent (MTA) on both servers, whether that's postfix, LMTP, sendmail, or whatever.  On server A the MTA is configured to deliver locally.  On server B the MTA is configured to deliver onward to server A.  If B is up and A is down, B will still accept emails for onward delivery, but they'll be held in queue until A comes back up; once A comes back up, B will deliver onward all queued mails at its next configured queue run.

Note that any generalised anti-spam measures you put on A must be put on B as well, otherwise B will blindly accept a bunch of emails which A will later reject, leaving them to end up with the postmaster of servers A and B.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I don't planed to use some spam filter, as I we will read the Mails with Gmail (external Account -> IMAP) and think they will handle it, if not I must setup something :)